# Piecewise Functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have been working on problems "a" and "b" for the longest time. I know part "a" is not continuous because if I were to draw the graph I would have to pick up the pencil to draw the graph. I don't think this is formal enough, but not sure how to get formal. Then for "b" I thought the point was 0, but not sure it is correct.

[image: Problems]

Comment: You have the correct intuition, which is very good. Now, we just need to formalize your thoughts.

Comment: How would you go about formalizing my thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

a. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let us show that $f$ is not continuous at $x$. Let define the following sequences: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},u_n:=\frac{\lfloor 10^n x\rfloor}{10^n},v_n:=\frac{\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor+\sqrt{2}}{10^n}.$$
$(u_n)_n$ and $(v_n)_n$ are both convergent to $x$ but $(u_n)_n$ is sequence of rational numbers, while $(v_n)_n$ is a sequence of irrational numbers. Therefore, one has: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},f(u_n)=1,f(v_n)=-1.$$
Hence, $(f(u_n))_n$ goes to 1, while $(f(v_n))_n$ goes to -1. If $f$ was continuous at $x$, since $\lim u_n=x=\lim v_n$, one would have $\lim f(u_n)=\lim f(v_n)$, which is not the case. Finally, $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

I let the point b. for you.

**Remark.** In point a. you can claim that there exist a sequence of rational numbers and a sequence of irrational numbers that both go to $x$ without construct them. The point is that for all real number $x$, there exist a rational number and an irational number as close as we want to $x$.